# tensorboard on docker jupyter notebook stuck

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

i made env for gpu
so i installed
ubuntu 18.04,
docker ,  NVIDIA Docker
and download docker image tensorflow/tensorflow: latest-gpu-jupyter
then i make container follow command on google chrome and firefox

```
sudo docker run --gpus all -it -p 8888:8888 -p 0.0.0.0:6006:6006   -v "$(pwd)"/Desktop/docker:/tf/docker     tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-jupyter
```

everything goes well except tensorboard

then i checked tensor board log file and re installed tensorbord
,sadly it does`n work well
i userd this command for tensorboard

```
%reload_ext tensorboard
%tensorboard --logdir {logs_base_dir} 
%tensorboard --logdir=./logs/fit/20210308-085859
%tensorboard --logdir=runs
%tensorboard --logdir tf_logs/
```

but return like this

**Reusing TensorBoard on port 6007 (pid 58), started 0:03:41 ago. (Use '!kill 58' to kill it.)**

**127.0.0.1 refused to connect**

i used command "!kill 58" and restart tensorboard but same log returned

then used this command

```
sudo docker exec -it 9dff3d5802df bash

#in the container 
tensorboard --logdir=./logs/fit/20210308-085859
```

but connection was refused

so i bilud up to local env (not virtual env)

tensorboard goes well

?what wrong ? i hope to use jupyter notebook, docker env for tensorboard

Comment: plus:multi gpu 1080ti and nvidia driver 450